# jScrollPane with JWPlayer javascript playlist

Tags: jwplayer, playlist, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm trying to use jScrollPane ( http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ ) with JWPlayer 5.2 playlist ( http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/23/creating-a-javascript-playlist ) but with no luck: the playlist is alright but the jScrollPane is not attached

I'm using JWPlayer 5.2 since the above tutorial states this is one of the "working" version with javascript playlist; anyway, no problem with the player, just with the playlist

Here's my demo: http://www.ivansweb.com/_test/player/jwplayer/index.php

Please, can you help?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are initiliazing jScrollPane on the jw_playlist_playlist div. This div seems to be generated by JWPlayer and is not here at the moment you try to add the scrollbar.

You should fire the jScrollPane initialization when you are sure JWPlayer is ready and has created the playlist. I am not familiar with JWPlayer but it looks like it has [different events](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference#Events) you could use or this ;)

Comment: Thanks skiplecariboo, at last I dropped jScrollPane and used jScroller 0.4, which made things easier